keycloak-angular 26 is unable to find keycloak-js
In our Angular 18 application we are switching from Keycloak version 25 to 26. This combination of library versions in our package.json was running fine:
{
   ...
   "keycloak-angular": "^16.0.1",
   "keycloak-js": "^25.0.1",
   ...
}

Now we tried to switch to the keycloak-js version 26:
{
   ...
   "keycloak-angular": "^16.1.0",
   "keycloak-js": "^26.0.5",
   ...
}

But now when building we get this:

The question is why keycloak-js cannot be found by keycloak-angular when it has worked before. Here is the tsconfig.json:
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "ES2022",
        "useDefineForClassFields": false,
        "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": ["./src/app/core/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["./src/app/shared/*"]
        },
        "resolveJsonModule": true, // Enable JSON imports (needed to import package.json in e.g. app/core/services/version.service.ts)
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true // Allow default imports from modules with no default export (needed to import package.json in e.g. app/core/services/version.service.ts)
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}

For the field moduleResolution I have tried "bundler" instead of "node" but that throws another error:

If I reset moduleResolution back to node and keycloak-js back to 25.0.1 everything is ok again. Any ideas?

I had raised a github issue for this scenario - Github issue - Enable keycloak-js to work with "node" bundler, types are not recognized in angular and application not starting.
Which pointed me to ticket which was what I duplicated - Github issue - Typescript Cannot find module keycloak-js or its corresponding type declarations. #33778
So the conclusion seems to be that "moduleResolution": "bundler" is the correct fix for this issue.
It is also explicitely mentioned in their Upgrading Guide.
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    ...

The error you are getting might be resolved by importing the interface/type at the root level, could you try.
import { InputSwitchModule, InputSwitchChangeEvent } from 'primeng/inputswitch';

Instead of drilling down to the interface level.
Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, very good explanation. "bundler" is the way to go and unfortunately it collided with the "wrong" primeng import.

After making changes to the configuration or dependencies, it's always a good idea to clear the npm cache and reinstall everything:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install


That might be a solution if your dependencies get messed up but is not the solution for this particular problem.

You can try to declare global type for keycloak-js like this:
declare module 'keycloak-js' {
  export * from 'keycloak-js/lib/keycloak';
}

Create folder types and put the keycloak-js.d.ts inside your types folder.
And include it to your main tsconfig.json file compilerOptions:
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./types"],

